# How do I plot the Pearson's correlation between numerous time points?

Tags: r, matrix, pearson-correlation

I was given a cDNA dataset, from which I extract the cdc15 experiment:

```
cdc15 <- dat[, (23:46)]
```

I then plot a correlation matrix between the time points in the CDc15 experiment using Pearson's correlation:

```
    # Calculate a correlation matrix between the time points (use Pearson's correlation).
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
library(minerva)
library(ggpmisc)

mat <- as.matrix(cdc15[, -1])
cor.test(x = mat[, 1], y = mat[, 2], method = "pearson", 
         use = "pairwise.complete.obs")

    ggscatter(cdc15, x = "YAL001C", "YAL002W", fill = "time", add = "reg.line", 
title = "Correlation matrix between time points of 
          cdc15 temperature-sensitive mutant", conf.int = TRUE, cor.coef = TRUE, 
          cor.method = "pearson", xlab = "log ratio YAL001C", 
          ylab = "log ratio YAL002W")
```

However, the code gave me an error when I try to plot:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , x) : undefined columns selected
```

mat[,1]
> print(mat[,1])
YAL001C   YAL002W   YAL003W   YAL004W   YAL005C   YAL007C   YAL008W   YAL009W
0.09        NA     -0.22        NA     -1.33        NA      0.04     -0.02
YAL010C   YAL011W   YAL012W   YAL013W   YAL014C   YAL015C   YAL016W   YAL017W
-0.06        NA     -0.94        NA      0.34      0.08      0.15     -0.69
YAL018C   YAL019W   YAL020C   YAL021C   YAL022C   YAL023C   YAL024C   YAL025C
0.61      0.36     -0.42      0.17     -0.24     -0.35     -0.08      1.04
YAL026C   YAL027W   YAL028W   YAL029C   YAL030W   YAL031C   YAL032C   YAL033W
-0.23        NA        NA     -0.40        NA     -0.37        NA      0.19

What's causing the error?

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for clarifying in the comments where the data comes from ("The data is derived from: rdrr.io/cran/minerva/man/Spellman.html"); this information is very useful for troubleshooting the problem you are having.

From the website:

> This data set contains a subset of yeast cell cycle data taken from
> Spellman et al. (1998) (See the reference below). Spellman et al.
> (1998) monitored the genome-wide mRNA levels for 6108 yeast genes at
> 7-minute intervals for 119 minutes. A total of 256 genes were
> identified to oscillate significantly in at least two data sets. This
> example data set contains the log ratios of these 256 genes at the
> first 16 time points(from 0 min to 105 min).

Based on this, the values in the dataset you are working with (mRNA levels) are not raw data, but relative values (log ratios). This affects the ways in which you can analyse them and it does not make sense to use a `cor.test()` the way you have in your question.

There are many ways to analyse correlations in this dataset, and I would suggest these steps as a good place to begin:

- Starting with the Spellman dataset, take a subset for analysis and include the "time" variable (first column):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
library(minerva)
library(ggpmisc)

data(Spellman)
dat <- Spellman
cdc15 <- select(dat, 1, 23:46)
```

- Plot the data to visualise correlations between variables:

```
cdc15 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(time)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ name, ncol = 4) +
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = "lm") +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ x,
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label..,
                                 ..rr.label..,
                                 sep = "~~~~")), 
               parse = TRUE)
```

[image: example_3.png]

(linear models don't do a very good job here, as there are patterns in the fluctuation of mRNA levels over time)

- Convert the data to a matrix to facilitate heatmaps / cor.tests:

```
mat <- as.matrix(cdc15)[,-1]
rownames(mat) <- cdc15$time
heatmap(t(mat), Colv = NA, xlab = "Time")
```

[image: example_4.png]

(This shows a lot of variance within and between variables)

- the [pheatmap](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pheatmap/versions/1.0.12/topics/pheatmap) package usually generates nicer plots, so give that a try:

```
pheatmap::pheatmap(t(mat), cluster_cols = FALSE)
```

[image: example_5.png]

- Choose two of the variables and evaluate correlation across all timepoints

```
cor.test(x = mat[,1], y = mat[,2])

#   Pearson's product-moment correlation
#
# data:  mat[, 1] and mat[, 2]
# t = -2.0605, df = 21, p-value = 0.05195
# alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  -0.703393088  0.002537664
# sample estimates:
#        cor 
# -0.4100935
```

(There is a correlation between the two variables, but it's not very strong)

- Plot the two variables:

```
ggscatter(cdc15, x = "YAR035W", y = "YAR043C", add = "reg.line",
          title = "Correlation matrix between time points of cdc15 temperature-sensitive mutant",
          conf.int = TRUE, cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson",
          xlab = "log ratio YAR035W", ylab = "log ratio YAR043C")
```

[image: example_6.png]

- See what it looks like if you colour the dots by "time":

```
ggscatter(cdc15, x = "YAR035W", y = "YAR043C", fill = "time", shape = 21, add = "reg.line",
          title = "Correlation matrix between time points of cdc15 temperature-sensitive mutant",
          conf.int = TRUE, cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson",
          xlab = "log ratio YAR035W", ylab = "log ratio YAR043C")
```

[image: example_7.png]

- Visualise correlations between all variables (samples) over time:

```
corrplot::corrplot(corr = mat, is.corr = FALSE, method = "color")
```

[image: example_8.png]

Comment: does it make sense to plot time point vs time point (your first example)? My table consists of the experiment with various time points (column) and genes (row). And how do I add a gradient legend?

Comment: The data is derived from: https://rdrr.io/cran/minerva/man/Spellman.html

Comment: I've edited my answer to give more relevant advice/examples, but if you need help with statistics please ask on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ where they have much more detailed explanations on why/when/how to analyse data e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/133171 (StackOverflow is more geared towards professional programmers)

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the code (see above). But there's still an error: `Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , x) : undefined columns selected`.

Comment: Not sure. What does `mat[, 1]` print?

Comment: I've edited the question with print(mat[,1])

Comment: Ok, change `x = "YAR035W", y = "YAR043C"` to `x = "YAL001C", y = "YAL002W"` and try again. If that doesn't work, drop `fill = "time", shape = 21,`.

Comment: I tried `x = "YAL001C", y = "YAL002W"` and it didn't work. I need a legend of the color gradient, so I kept the fill = "time". I dropped the shape = 21. But I still get the same error `Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , x) : undefined columns selected`. The code is updated to reflect the change.

Comment: I also have a follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67901096/how-do-i-draw-a-profile-plot-in-r

(Next time, will start posting stats.stackexchange.com instead, as you suggested).